# Ruby CSV#fetch case sensitivness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have simple csv file that has the following header: 'NYC'.
I use CSV fetch method:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-fetch

the problem is that when I use fetch with 'NYC' it works properly but when I use fetch with 'nyc' it returns:

```
KeyError: key not found: nyc
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option [`:header_converters`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#HeaderConverters). You can set it to:

- `:downcase` Calls downcase() on the header String.
- `:symbol` The header String is downcased, spaces are replaced with underscores, non-word characters are dropped, and finally to_sym() is called.

Example:

```
require 'CSV'

CSV.parse("NYC\nfoo", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  row[:nyc] #=> "foo"
end
```